# vala iterator next_value method return type

Tags: iterator, vala

From vala tutorial:

alternative iterator protocol: "T? next_value()"
If the iterator object has a .next_value() function that returns a nullable type then we iterate by calling this function until it returns null.

I write some code, but got an error.

the error message:

> error: return type of `Something.next_value' must be nullable
>
> foreach (string s in A) {
>
> ```
>                      ^
> ```

I don't understand, it is nullable already in my next_value return type.

How to correct this code?

```
public static void main() {
    stdout.printf("hello\n");
    var A = new Something<string> ({"aa", "bb"});

    foreach (string s in A) {
        stdout.puts(s);
        stdout.puts ("\n");
    }
    
}

public class Something<T> : Object {
    public T[]  data;
    private int _size;
    private int _i = 0;

    public Something (owned T[] a){
        this.data  = a;
        this._size = data.length;
    }

    public Something<T> iterator(){
        return this;
    }
    
    // error: return type of `Something.next_value' must be nullable
    // foreach (string s in A) {
    //                        ^

    public T? next_value () {
        return _i < _size ? data[_i++] : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you reinventing Gee.ArrayList? http://valadoc.org/#!api=gee-0.10/Gee.ArrayList

Comment: @Jens Mühlenhoff
Do you have any idea? 
Actually if I impl next() and get(). it will work. 
But I don't want to do so. 
Because I want keep the get() method like: `var a = A[2]`. 
So I have this problem. If It is a bug?

Comment: It seem to be a bug to me. You can report it to https://bugzilla.gnome.org/ (product "vala").

Comment: BTW: Nullable handling with generic types ca be tricky with Vala, especially when using value types. So this might have something to do with generics. You can try to write a specialized class for `string` and see if the error persists.

Comment: If you want to use `get()` for an index and use `get()` for the iterator there should be no conflict because usually you would implement the iterator as a nested class. This is shown in the example from the Vala tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared that the generic data type must be nullable, which is correct. So when you pass the specific data type as a type argument make sure it is also nullable. The line:

```
var A = new Something<string> ({"aa", "bb"});
```

should be:

```
var A = new Something<string?> ({"aa", "bb"});
```